# How to use If in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How to use If in Pine Script? I tried but get this error:

> Error: Syntax error at input 'alert' (V5)

```
boolValue=ta.crossover(ta.ema(close,10),ta.ema(close,20))

if(boolValue)
 alert("A",freq=alert.freq_all)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if boolValue
    alert("A",freq=alert.freq_all)
```

You need to write your if statement and then on a new line indent by 4 spaces or a tab and then place write your next block of code

Comment: Can I add multiple statements inside one if statement ?

Comment: You can use an else or else if after the first if statement